# Webpage not working on Linux

Tags: ajax, linux, html

I have a webpage that uses PHP, AJAX and JavaScript to display some graphs and other data. When using Apache 2.2.1, the page runs fine when hosted in Windows but on running in Linux, i can see my page elements but i do not see any data, which i believe means that no data is being received through the AJAX calls. What's going wrong here ?

----------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------------------------

Alright, i checked the return value of the AJAX calls ( the responseText ). Its coming out to be null. What could be the problem ?

Comment: @vahidchakoshy CentOS and Ubuntu.

Comment: please get error of ajax call & url with firebug and add to question and location of project

Comment: The AJAX call status is 200 (OK). No data is being returned. Why is this happening only on Linux ?

Comment: can you add php code in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed PHP? Are you running apache on the linux box? Can you echo a string with PHP? Do you have javascript enabled on the web browser?

Comment: I access the page using the same browser as on Windows, apart from accessing it from the Linux machine too. PHP is installed and simple 'hello world' .php page was running.

Comment: Could be a permissions issue. Make sure PHP and apache can access the necessary files.

Comment: Trying to diagnose a problem like this without more information is like doing surgery blindfolded.

Comment: I can access other files in the same folder.

Comment: Check the ajax calls to see if they are using backslashes instead of unix forward slashes? I haven't really done web hosting on windows, so not sure if that's a thing.

Comment: I dont have slashes in my code except for one location and that uses forward slashes only.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13596/discussion-between-conner-and-cygnus)

Answer (score 1):

please be sure if filesystem really is the same in windows and in linux. i doubt that it is regarding hosting pages.

Comment: Uhmm..i didnt get what you're trying to say..Shouldnt the same script run irrespective of OS ?

Comment: running on local os and in hosting os are different. like if i write e.g. a django app, i access my static files in a total different way than in hosting os in linux. i am not sure, i never deployed php page onto linux, but this is most probably the reason why your page is not running..

Comment: make sure that the folder in which your page lives is accessable and not in doc root.

Comment: what is your apache modul? mod_php  ?

Comment: take a look here http://blog.nuclear-dawn.com/2010/06/deploying-php-applications-on-red-hat-linux/

Comment: Is there a way to check that from command line ? The server on which i was testing is experiencing problems since a couple of minutes and i cant access web pages.

Comment: you have something wrong in file hierarchie that your files are not reachable. todos: 1) check if all folders on the path until your project are permitted for being read. 2) check if the project folder itself is also okay for reading. as i said, i am not linux guru.. if you solve the problem, please update us how you did it. it is good for other people with same problem..